# MailBox unavailable message while sending email from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email, iis, smtp, asp.net-membership

I am trying to sending registration **email** from **asp.net login** page. But the console shows this error..

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Delivery is not allowed to this address.
```

What can cause this error, code or the misconfiguration of the **stmp server**. I am hosting on commercial server not my own.

Comment: Does the address you're trying to send an e-mail to REALLY exist?

Comment: Yes the address is there ...

Comment: to wich domain you are trying to send the email? (google, yahoo?)

Comment: I tried both yahoo and hotmail.. not google

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419962/setting-up-mailsettings-in-asp-net-web-config  I asked the same question here too please view it

Answer (score 0):

try
**yourClientName.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;**

for example:

```
SmtpClient client;
client = new SmtpClient("smtp.myserver.com", 25);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(""))
{
     System.Net.NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("", "");
     client.Credentials = credential;
}
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpdeliverymethod.aspx