# setting up mailsettings in asp.net web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, smtp, asp.net-membership

I am trying to send registration email from asp.net login page. but there appear different type of issues

```
<mailSettings>
   <smtp from="mail@spiralsnet.com">
      <network host="localhost" defaultCredentials ="false" username="mail@domain.com" password="passord"/>
   </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

when I use this setting I get this error

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

When I use this settings

```
<mailSettings>
   <smtp from="mail@domain.com">
      <network host="localhost" defaultCredentials ="true"/>
   </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

the it generates the error

> mailbox unavailable

I am confused about the `localhost` part. should I leave it or change it..

Comment: The host needs to be a valid SMTP server, localhost won't work unless your machine has got one.

Comment: how to check the smtp name.. I am confused.. should it be smtp.mydomainname.com @bazz